# Plotting Circles on a Google Map and issues with zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am plotting some points on a google map using their circle API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

The problem I am having is that not all of the points show up on the map with the predefined zoom level of 4, if I zoom in just one more level then they do show up. Is there anyway to get them to show up even at a far away zoom?

Here is my code for adding the marker to a map:

```
addMarker: function(opts) {
  var gLatLng = this.gLatLng(opts);
  var radius = opts.population / 20;
  var self = this;

  this._configure_circle(radius);

  var circle = {
      strokeColor: this.color,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: this.stroke,
      fillColor: this.color,
      fillOpactiy: 1,
      map: this.map,
      center: gLatLng,
      radius: this.radius
  }
  var gCirle = new google.maps.Circle(circle);
  gCirle.setValues({_id: opts._id});
  this.markers.push(gCirle);

  google.maps.event.addListener(gCirle, 'click', function(event){
    self.map.setZoom(8);
    self.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(gCirle.getCenter().lat(), gCirle.getCenter().lng()));
    Session.set('currentMapArea', gCirle.get('_id'));
  });

  return gCirle;
},
_configure_circle: function(num) {
    if(num > 4000) {
        this.stroke = 50;
        this.color = '#66FF00'
        this.radius = num + 300;
    } else if(num <= 4000 && num > 3400) {
        this.stroke = 25;
        this.color = '#44E030';
        this.radius = num + 200;
    } else {
        this.stroke = 15;
        this.color = '#22DD60';
        this.radius = num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `LatLngBounds`-object, extend these LatLngBounds with the bounds of each circle and when you have finished the creation of the circles call the `fitBounds`-method of the map by passing the LatLngBounds as argument.